# django admin - use filter horizontal on a many to many field with intermediate table

Tags: django, django-admin

Is it possible to use `filter_horizontal` for a field which is a `ManyToManyField` with an intermediate table such as with those without intermediate tables?

e.g:

```
class A(models.Model):
    f1 = models.ManyToManyField(B)
    f2 = models.ManyToManyField(C, through='T')

class B(models.Model):
    pass

class C(models.Model):
    pass

class T(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A)
    c = models.ForeignKey(C)

class AAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    filter_horizontal = ('f1', 'f2', )
```

Comment: There's no error and no widget is showing

Answer (score 6):

When you have a many to many field with an intermediate table, it's not possible to display the regular, filter horizontal, or filter vertical widget. The reason for this is that the intermediate table may have extra fields that can not be displayed in those widgets.

It is possible to display the related model as an inline. See the docs on [working with many-to-many intermediary models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#working-with-many-to-many-intermediary-models) for more info.

Comment: So it is not possible even if the intermediate table doesn't have any extra field? Anyway I tried what the documentation said, but it doesn't work for me. If it worth I'm using django 1.4.2.

Comment: No, it looks like it's not possible, unless you're willing to dive into the internal code and see what's going on. Using inlines for many to many fields definitely works in Django 1.4 (see [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/admin/#working-with-many-to-many-intermediary-models)). I can't tell why it's not working in your case because you haven't shown your code.

Comment: @gorus the SO post that you are linking does not help as the OP is not using an intermediate table. Do you have an idea on how to modify the linked answer?

Comment: @gorus OK, starting from the post you linked, I could modify it to make it work with intermediate table. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44714416

Comment: The `auto_created` trick described in this [Django ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/12203#comment:22) might help.

Answer (score 3):

The widget's name is **FilteredSelectMultiple** and you have to override **formfield_for_manytomany** method in your admin view. Here is what i have used.
I have a Company model with manytomany courses field with Member as an intermediate model.

```
class Company(models.Model):
    courses = models.ManyToManyField('courses.Course', through='Member', related_name='companies')

class Member(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(get_user_model(),
    related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s",
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
)
organization = TenantForeignKey(
    Company, related_name="organization_users", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

This is my admin view

```
class CompanyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def formfield_for_manytomany(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        db = kwargs.get('using')

        if db_field.name == 'courses':
            kwargs['widget'] = FilteredSelectMultiple(
                db_field.verbose_name, is_stacked=False
            )
        else:
            return super().formfield_for_manytomany(db_field, request, **kwargs)
        if 'queryset' not in kwargs:
            queryset = Course.objects.filter(is_active=True)
            if queryset is not None:
                kwargs['queryset'] = queryset
        form_field = db_field.formfield(**kwargs)
        msg = 'Hold down “Control”, or “Command” on a Mac, to select more than one.'
        help_text = form_field.help_text
        form_field.help_text = (
            format_lazy('{} {}', help_text, msg) if help_text else msg
        )
        return form_field
```

Comment: This works great. I would make a couple of tweaks. For ex., you don't need to set `db` in the first line of the overridden method because that variable is not used again; and I would change the structure of the code branching. Basically tho, Django's own `formfield_for_manytomany()` method returns `None` if it detects an intermediary table, so you override that method and force it to return a formfield by calling `db_field.formfield()` directly. I think you can then set the queryset on that formfield, so you don't have to put it into `kwargs` beforehand, but fundamentally, this answer is good.