# filter_horizon or filter_vertical for InLine ManyToMany field at Django 2.x Admin

Tags: python, django, django-2.1

Here is my model relation (copied from Django 2.1 official documentation - my model is an exact copy of this **but only the model names are different.**):

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(
        Person,
        through='Membership',
        through_fields=('group', 'person'),
    )

class Membership(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Here is my admin.py:

```
class MembershipInLine(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Membership

class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        MembershipInLine,
    ]
```

I get the field on my Person page like this:
[Current view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ff9zl.png)

But instead I would like to have this style of view:
[Desired view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPCwc.png)

I've found `filter_horizontal` and `filter_vertical` in the [official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.filter_horizontal), but I can't figure out how I can use them with inline. How can I do that?

**Edit:**

I've tried as described in the docs:

```
class MembershipInLine(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Membership # (and also tried with = Group.members.through)
    filter_horizontal = ('group', )
```

But it throws:

> (admin.E020) The value of 'filter_horizontal[0]' must be a many-to-many field.

Comment: According to the docs, filter horizontal and filter vertical are meant for many to may field.So in your case they can be used with Group.

Comment: @not2acoder My model is already ManyToMany

Comment: So filter_horizontal can be used in group admin, a model with a manytomany field, not with person.

Comment: It doesn't work either with your suggestion or with my first approach (using intermediary model) @not2acoder as you can see at the edit section

Comment: Since you are using Intermediate through model , it won't be easy to display filter_horizontal in this case, see this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44714416/django-admin-interface-using-horizontal-filter-with-manytomany-field-with-inter

Answer (score 0):

I'd consult with the auth admin panel for group's permissions. Try something like

```
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ()
    ordering = ()
    filter_horizontal = ('membership',)

    def formfield_for_manytomany(self, db_field, request=None, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == 'membership':
            qs = kwargs.get('queryset', db_field.remote_field.model.objects)
            # Avoid a major performance hit resolving membership names which
            # triggers a content_type load:
            kwargs['queryset'] = qs.select_related('content_type')
        return super().formfield_for_manytomany(db_field, request=request, **kwargs)
```

https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/admin.py#L29

Comment: I've tried exactly how you suggest. I still get the same error.